# im trying to understand this string of code and what it is saying, specifilicy this '[^|]+'

Tags: sql, oracle

I had an a co-worker email a query who is no longer with the company and im trying to understand what it is saying.

```
, case when regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 1) <> nvl(sum(cd.actl_qty),0)
    then regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 1) - nvl(sum(cd.actl_qty),0) else null end Curr_Var
, case when regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 1) is null then 'First Count'
    when regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 1) = nvl(sum(cd.actl_qty),0)
        then 'Processed'
    when regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 1) > 0 and (regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 2) > 0 or regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 2) is null) and sum(cd.actl_qty) is null
        then 'Recount'
    when regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 1) <> nvl(sum(cd.actl_qty),0)
        and regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 1) = case when LENGTH(c_qty)-LENGTH(REPLACE(c_qty,'|',''))>1 then regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 2) else null end
        then 'Confirmed'
    when regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 1) <> nvl(sum(cd.actl_qty),0)
        and (regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 2) = nvl(sum(cd.actl_qty),0)
                or regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 3) = nvl(sum(cd.actl_qty),0)
                or regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 4) = nvl(sum(cd.actl_qty),0)
                or regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 5) = nvl(sum(cd.actl_qty),0)
                or regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 6) = nvl(sum(cd.actl_qty),0))
        then 'Expire Recent'
    when regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 1) <> nvl(sum(cd.actl_qty),0)
        and case when LENGTH(c_qty)-LENGTH(REPLACE(c_qty,'|',''))>1 then regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 2) else null end is null
        then 'Recount'
    when regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 1) <> nvl(sum(cd.actl_qty),0)
        and regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 1) <> case when LENGTH(c_qty)-LENGTH(REPLACE(c_qty,'|',''))>1
        then regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 2) else null end then 'Recount' else null end Directive
, regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 1) as Last_Cnt
, case when LENGTH(c_qty)-LENGTH(REPLACE(c_qty,'|',''))>1 then regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 2) else null end as Prev_Cnt1
, case when LENGTH(c_qty)-LENGTH(REPLACE(c_qty,'|',''))>2 then regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 3) else null end as Prev_Cnt2
, case when LENGTH(c_qty)-LENGTH(REPLACE(c_qty,'|',''))>3 then regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 4) else null end as Prev_Cnt3
, case when LENGTH(c_qty)-LENGTH(REPLACE(c_qty,'|',''))>4 then regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 5) else null end as Prev_Cnt4
, case when LENGTH(c_qty)-LENGTH(REPLACE(c_qty,'|',''))>5 then regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 6) else null end as Prev_Cnt5
```

I've tried researching the statements with no luck, can someone please explain it to me thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`regexp_substr()` function is used to extract a substring based on a regular expression.

`[^|]+` is a regular expression that means a string that doesn't contains a vertical bar `|`.

`regexp_substr(c_qty, '[^|]+', 1, 1)` is return the first occurrence of a string that doesn't contains a vertical bar from `c_qty` column starting the first character from the string.

This pattern is commonly used to extract items from a pipe-separated list.  For example, `REGEXP_SUBSTR('A|B', '[^|]+', 1, 1)` returns `A`, `REGEXP_SUBSTR('A|B', '[^|]+', 1, 2)` returns `B`, etc.  This kind of code often implies an issue with the data model; it looks like someone was inserting non-relational data into a relational database.  The query would be easier if each column only contained atomic data types.  An extra join is much easier than parsing lists.

**More information**

- [Oracle / PLSQL: REGEXP_SUBSTR Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php)
- [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm)